# Fragment not showing previous data when coming from another fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

In my android activity I am using multiple fragments, I am successfully switching these fragments according to my requirement but problem is that when I am switching Fragment 1 to Fragment 2 and back from Fragment 2 to Fragment 1, Fragment 1 not showing previous data Fragment 1 start from stretch, but I want to show previous data same as I was selected.

Here is my code for go Fragment 1 (fragment_search_customerProfile) to Fragment 2 (fragment_CustomerInfo):

```
FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.filterFram, new fragment_Search());

FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cpFrame);
layout.removeAllViewsInLayout();

transaction.remove(new fragment_search_customerProfile()).commit();
```

Here is my code for back Fragment 1 (fragment_search_customerProfile) fromFragment 2 (fragment_CustomerInfo):

```
FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();


FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

Log.d("fragment_Search", fromSearch + "");
transaction.replace(R.id.custIndoFram, new fragment_search_customerProfile());

FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.custIndoFram);

layout.removeAllViewsInLayout();

transaction.remove(new fragment_CustomerInfo()).commit();
```

Can anyone explain me how can I stay save my fragment data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `transaction.replace(R.id.filterFram, new fragment_Search());`
 you can use transaction.add to add fragment while having the data of first one
`transaction.add(R.id.filterFram, new fragment_Search());
transaction.addToBackStack(null);`

From fragment two you can use .show instead of replace to show the first fragment
and hide fragment two from the first one.           `transaction.show(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("firstFragmentTag")).commit();`

Comment: Let me check first

Comment: Its giving me the same result as previous

Comment: Try adding it to backstack too.

Comment: let me check sir

Comment: transaction.add(R.id.filterFram, new fragment_Search());
                transaction.addToBackStack(fragment_search_customerProfile.class.getName());

Comment: I am using these lines

Comment: because you are using .replace in second fragment too. try .show() I edited the answer to show it.

Comment: Thank you Mark Samy

Answer (score 0):

You can simple keep the instances of the fragments, so in your `Activity` you would have fields like that.

```
private Fragment fragment1;
private Fragment fragment2;
```

And now you can use the sexy `replace()` option,

To add `Fragment1`

```
if (fragment1 == null) {
    fragment1 = new fragment_Search();
}
FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.filterFram, fragment1);
```

and same for `Fragment2`

And you can hold the state of the fragment (data it retrieves) in the `Fragment` itself, and in your `onViewCreated()` you check, if the state is not `null`, you update the view immediately.

```
class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    private State state;

    public void onViewCreated(View v) {
        if (state != null) {
            // Update UI here
        }
    }

}
```

UPDATE

Using your own code

```
private Fragment fragment1; // This is a field outside of below method


if (fragment1 == null) {
    fragment1 = new fragment_Search();
}
FragmentManager manager = getChildFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.filterFram, fragment1).commit();

FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cpFrame);
layout.removeAllViewsInLayout();
```

Going to fragment2 should be the same, and this code is used to go to Fragment1 and Fragment2, doesn't matter if you are going back or first time.

Comment: I am not working in activity I am working in fragments.

Comment: The same should work for fragment as well, you just need to use getChildFragmentManager() instead

Comment: Can you please add these with my code which past on my question because I cannot understand in which fragment I add this code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add fragment instead of remove or replace